# which function is used in these extended classes?

Tags: inheritance, polymorphism, extend

I'm trying to understand polymorphism and Inheritance. So I wrote some code and tried to retrace what happens.

I just don't get why the three last methods don't also print "B". The reference variable of the object is always Top, and the parameters are always objects of classes extending Top. And if those last three methods print C, K and X: Shouldn't tm.m(mm); print a J?
I don't understand it, can someone please explain it to me?

```
public class polymorphie
{
    class Top
    {
        public void m( Top p ) { System.out.print("B"); }
        public void m( Bottom p ) { System.out.print("C"); }

    }

    class Middle extends Top
    {
        public void m( Bottom p ) { System.out.print("K"); }
        public void m( Middle p ) { System.out.print("J"); }       
    }

    class Bottom extends Middle
    {
        public void m( Middle p ) { System.out.print("W"); }
        public void m( Bottom p ) { System.out.print("X"); }
    }


        public void run()
        {
            Top tt = new Top();
            Top tm = new Middle();
            Top tb = new Bottom();
            Middle mm = new Middle();
            Middle mb = new Bottom();
            Bottom bb = new Bottom();

            tt.m(tt);                       // B
            tt.m(tm);
            tt.m(tb);
            tt.m(mm);
            tt.m(mb);
            tm.m(tt);
            tm.m(tm);
            tm.m(tb);
            tm.m(mm);                       // why not J?
            tm.m(mb);
            tb.m(tt);
            tb.m(tm);
            tb.m(tb);
            tb.m(mm);         
            tb.m(mb);               

            System.out.println();            

            tt.m(bb);                       // C 

            tm.m(bb);                       // K   

            tb.m(bb);                       // X
        }      
}
```

Comment: Could you add the complete output to your post?  I posted an answer, but deleted after I realized I misread, and that led to more questions.

Comment: Output is BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB  C  K  X

Answer (score 1):

The result is that the output of the line `tm.m(mm);` is B because the invoked method is `public void m( Top p )` of the **Top** class.

Two concepts here:

1. in the line `Top tm = new Middle();` , even if you costruct `tm` with the Middle class costuctor, it is still a reference to an object of type **Top**, so the methods of `tm` object will be the methods of the **Top** class. The implementantion of these methods is that written in Top class, if they are not overriden in its subclass.
2. The signature  of the involved method is not the same in the top class **Top** and its subclass **Middle** : the method `public void m( Top p )` doesn't exist in the Middle class. So, the top class method is not overriden by the method of its subclass.

You should look to the lines

```
 tm.m(bb);                       // K   
 tb.m(bb);                       // X
```

as an example of what i'm saying. In fact **tm** is a Top, but the method `public void m(Bottom)` exists in both classes Top and Middle, so the implementation of Middle class is used and the method prints 'K' instead of 'C'. Same reason for **tb** : it is a reference to a Top object, but in the "granmother" class Top, the method `public void m( Bottom p )` is overriden because it is in both classes with exactly the same signature.